# JQuery UI drag and drop without the drag/drop action as such

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have an in-progress web page that needs puch touch adding but you should get the idea at http://mailandthings.co.uk/test123.htm

Is it possible at all, mainly really for mobile devices, so that instead of dragging and dropping, you can click on one item, which would in effect highlight it, and then drop it by tapping somewhere else an area of the screen where you would normally drag into?

This is partly to get around an issue on smaller displays where some scrolling takes place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes but it isn't a bug or error.  I am asking or trying to find out/establish if the kind of functionality I am referring to is possible or not?  I am only asking on here also as not been able to find anywhere else on the web looking so thought someone else may know of a way?

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It is possible. But it will need some help. Take a look at TouchPunch, this library should help you to perform drag and drop. But selecting it and moving it without dragging it is a different scenario.